# Integer exponentiation in OCaml

Tags: integer, ocaml, floating-accuracy, exponentiation

Is there a function for integer exponentiation in OCaml? ** is only for floats. Although it seems to be mostly accurate, isn't there a possibility of precision errors, something like 2. ** 3. = 8. returning false sometimes? Is there a library function for integer exponentiation? I could write my own, but efficiency concerns come into that, and also I'd be surprised if there isn't such a function already.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Regarding the floating-point part of your question: OCaml calls the underlying system's `pow()` function. Floating-point exponentiation is a difficult function to implement, but it only needs to be faithful (that is, accurate to one [Unit in the Last Place](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place)) to make `2. ** 3. = 8.` evaluate to `true`, because `8.0` is the only `float` within one ULP of the mathematically correct result 8.

All math libraries should(*) be faithful, so you should not have to worry about this particular example. But [not all of them actually are](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/04/06/Non-experts-need-accurate-floating-point-the-most), so you are right to worry.

---

A better reason to worry would be, if you are using 63-bit integers or wider, that the arguments or the result of the exponentiation cannot be represented exactly as OCaml floats (actually IEEE 754 double-precision numbers that cannot represent `9_007_199_254_740_993` or 2<sup>53</sup> + 1). In this case, floating-point exponentiation is a bad substitute for integer exponentiation, not because of a weakness in a particular implementation, but because it is not designed to represent exactly integers that big.

---

(*) Another fun reference to read on this subject is “[A Logarithm Too Clever by Half](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/LOG10HAF.TXT)” by William Kahan.

Comment: Is floating-point exponentiation as fast as integer exponentiation given that the arguments are the same? Also, just to be clear, is your statement that floating-point exponentiation should be faithful true for all integers a,b for which -2^30 ≤ a^b < 2^30, or just for my particular example of 2 3 and 8?

Comment: @user2258552 Regarding speed: floating-point exponentiation is probably slower than a well-written integer one. Regarding the meaning of “should”: a faithful elementary function is accurate to one ULP across its definition domain. All libms should be faithful because it is a reasonable compromise between computational cost and accuracy that would make pretty much everyone happy. Accuracy to 0.5 ULP is a bit too much to expect of all libms because of the table-maker's dilemma, but accuracy to 1 ULP is achievable at reasonable cost. (but, again, pow() is one of the hardest elementary functions)

Comment: Regarding speed: in light of that, then it really makes very little sense to not include an integer exponentiation function in the standard library...

Answer (score 31):

Not in the standard library. But you can easily write one yourself (using [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) to be fast), or reuse an extended library that provides this. In [Batteries](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/), it is [Int.pow](http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc/BatInt.html#VALpow).

Below is a proposed implementation:

```
let rec pow a = function
  | 0 -> 1
  | 1 -> a
  | n -> 
    let b = pow a (n / 2) in
    b * b * (if n mod 2 = 0 then 1 else a)
```

If there is a risk of overflow because you're manipulating very big numbers, you should probably use a big-integer library such as [Zarith](http://forge.ocamlcore.org/projects/zarith), which provides all sorts of exponentiation functions.

(You may need the "modular exponentiation", computing `(a^n) mod p`; this can be done in a way that avoids overflows by applying the mod in the intermediary computations, for example in the function `pow` above.)

Comment: Great answer. Unfortunately, I could only pick one best answer :/. Also, I'm not convinced that this is always the fastest way to implement integer exponentiation. In fact, I think there's a Project Euler question (which I have yet to solve) along these lines. I really think integer exponentiation should be added to the standard library. Even if it is not any more efficient (which I'm not sure is true), it's a pretty common thing to need and having to convert and deconvert from floats is annoying. Of course importing a library isn't hard, but there's no reason this shouldn't be standard.

Comment: Well, if you have better ideas of how to implement integer implementation in the general case, feel free to suggest an implementation.

Comment: @user2258552 I do not agree with your premise that integer exponentiation is so common. In practice, you almost always work with small fixed exponents, or you *need* an arbitrary precision arithmetic as suggested by gasche. TL;DR: Stop to believe you need integer exponentiation on fixed precision ints and realize you need an arbitrary precision arithmetic library.

Answer (score 7):

Here's another implementation which uses exponentiation by squaring (like the one provided by @gasche), but this one is *tail-recursive*

```
let is_even n = 
  n mod 2 = 0

(* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring *)
let pow base exponent =
  if exponent < 0 then invalid_arg "exponent can not be negative" else
  let rec aux accumulator base = function
    | 0 -> accumulator
    | 1 -> base * accumulator
    | e when is_even e -> aux accumulator (base * base) (e / 2)
    | e -> aux (base * accumulator) (base * base) ((e - 1) / 2) in
  aux 1 base exponent
```

Comment: Note that tail-recursivity does not matter for a function logarithmic in its input. How could you ever blow the stack? Of course, if tail-recursivity gives a different viewpoint that reveals something interesting about the code, or makes it easier to read, then it can still be interesting.

Comment: @gasche you're right. This code does not make sense for 63 or 31 bit integers. An algorithm like that would make sense for arbitrary-precision numbers.