# How to structure an accumulator for fold_left with index access

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, ocaml, ref, fold

I want to write a function that takes a List `[a_n; a_n-1; ...; a_0]` with an accumulator `acc`.

The function is supposed to calculate the sum of every element in the whole list raised to the *i*'th power. The function `fold_left` will give `f` an integer. The formula is `acc + sum from i=0 to n of a_i ^ i`. My problem is that in `fold_left`:

```ml
let fold_left f acc l = 
 match l with 
 | [] -> acc
 | x::xs -> fold_left f (f x acc) xs
```

the accumulator always returns one integer -- so there's no reference for me to know what number the *i*'th element is.

---

So my question is how should I structure my `f` function.

`f` should be structured like this:

```
 f a_0 (f a_1 (...(f a_n acc)...))
```

I tried an imperative approach by using a `ref` variable that stores the previous values that `f` has calculated thus far. But I'm sure there are better solutions to this problem...

Comment: The **right** function for fold_**left**? ;-)

Comment: If you have tried something, even if it has not worked (or you wouldn't be _here_, right?) you should include it in your post. You may be close.

Answer (score 1):

The accumulator don't need to be an integer, it can be a tuple, or a record

```
type 'a acc = { pos:int; acc:'a }
```

Comment: actually the function fold_left will give f an integer. The formula is acc + sum from i=0 to n of a_i ^ i

Comment: You are still free to define the type of the accumulator: the type of fold_left is ('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a . As you can see, the type of f is not restricted to `int -> int -> int`.

Comment: Using a tuple or record as an accumulator may mean `fold_left` is returning more information that you need. You can use pattern-matching in a let binding or a match expression to isolate the information you need and discard the rest.

Comment: The accumulator should essentially be all of the state you need to keep track of as you iterate. The only thing it doesn't need to track is the current element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pair for the accumulator:

```ml
# let f (s, i) x =
      (s + pow x i, i + 1);;
val f : int * int -> int -> int * int = <fun>

# let sum_powers_left l = fst (List.fold_left f (0, 0) l);;
val sum_powers_left : int list -> int = <fun>


# let g x (s, i) =
      (s + pow x i, i + 1);;
val g : int -> int * int -> int * int = <fun>

# let sum_powers_right l = fst (List.fold_right g l (0, 0));;
val sum_powers_right : int list -> int = <fun>


# sum_powers_left [2000; 100; 20; 3];;   (* 1 + 100 + 20*20 + 3*3*3 *)
- : int = 528

# sum_powers_right [2000; 100; 20; 3];;  (* 2000*2000*2000 + 100*100 + 20 + 1 *)
- : int = 8000010021
```

where `pow x i` evaluates to `x` to the power of `i`. [Sadly it's not in the standard library.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16950687/integer-exponentiation-in-ocaml)

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a really imperative solution to your problem first.

A utility function so we can do integer exponentiation. We'll use `List.iter` to run an imperative loop over an `int list`.

```
let rec pow x =
  function
  | 0 -> 1
  | 1 -> x
  | n -> x * pow x (n - 1)
```

```
let lst = [1; 4; 7; 2]

let pos = ref 0
let sum = ref 0

let () = 
  List.iter 
    (fun x -> sum := !sum + pow x !pos; 
              pos := !pos + 1) 
    lst

Printf.printf "The sum is %d\n" !sum
```

There were two pieces of information we needed to keep track of across the iteration: `pos` and `sum`. In this imperative style, we kept track of them by mutating a value.

When we use `List.fold_left` and use an accumulator to contain this same state, we no longer need to mutate any values.

```
let (pos, sum) = 
  List.fold_left 
    (fun (p, s) x -> (p + 1, s + pow x p)) 
    (0, 0) 
    lst
```

You can see how the initial state provided mirrors the zeroes I provided in the imperative example.

If we look at how this progresses as it works over the list it's possible to get a better picture of how the accumulator tuple works.

```
List.fold_left f (0, 0) [1; 4; 7; 2]
List.fold_left f (1,  0 + pow 1 0) [4; 7; 2]
List.fold_left f (2,  1 + pow 4 1) [7; 2]
List.fold_left f (3,  5 + pow 7 2) [2]
List.fold_left f (4, 54 + pow 2 3) []
(4, 62)
```

Comment: I suggest a small modification to your `pow` function, to make it logarithmic instead of linear: [Integer exponentiation in Ocaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16950687/integer-exponentiation-in-ocaml). This is especially important if it is going to be called repeatedly by `fold_left` or `iter`.

Comment: I thought about that, but was going for the easiest version of `pow` to understand to not distract.

Answer (score 0):

`List.fold_left` can accept an accumulator of any type

```ml
(* given some pow function *)
let rec pow a b =
  match b with
  | 0 -> 1
  | _ -> a * pow a (b - 1)

(* your initial accumulator *)
let init = (0, 0) in 

(* your folding function *)
let f (i, r) v = 
  (i + 1, r + pow v i) in

(* note the output is a tuple of the last i and the sum *) 
let (i, result) = List.fold_left f init [10;20;30;40] in

(* print the result *)
Format.printf "result: %d\n" result
```

```
result: 64921
```

Check your work -

```
10^0 + 20^1 + 30^2 + 40^3 = 64921 ✅
```